# Contact management Android app

Tags: android, contact-manager

I am looking for an app for managing my contacts. I did quite a bit of research, but did not find what I am looking for:

- open source would be great
- being able to connect with my Linux Kubuntu computer (meaning synchronization. I am using Kmail / Kontact in KDE.)
- I am *not* interested in connecting with Facebook, Google+ or any other social platform
- the app should be secure - other apps should be able to get to my contacts unless I specifically allow them to, encryption would be nice (I am on Copperhead OS afterall)
- contacts should be stored as vCards if possible
- it is supposed to be a native App, no web-service
- no cloud service

Requested features:

- being able to tag contacts
- being able to put contacts in groups
- being able to add lots of different kinds of information about the contact
- being able act from the contacts (call from them, write with telegram from them, send a mail from them, etc.)

Comment: Won't fit all your needs (especially I'm unsure concerning the additional fields you might need), but you could use ownCloud/Nextcloud or Baïkal and sync your contacts via WebDAV. I'm using DAVDroid for that, and it works great. No dependencies to any "alien cloud service", all data in my hands. I'm not aware of a possibility to permit apps access to specific contacts only, by the way. And apart from that, be welcome to my Android app list on [Contact Managers and Dialers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer) :)

Comment: @Izzy: Solving the issue of synchronisation later - what app itself do you recommend then, keeping security in mind? I followed your link, but the list was a little confusing: What do all the icons mean - what is actually recommended?

Comment: @Izzy: What are you using?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but the icons are explained if you follow the "?" link at the top-right of the page :) I usually stick with the one that ships with the system, so I cannot really give a clear recommendation for a specific app. Considering it has access to your contacts, I'd chose one that doesn't require `INTERNET` itself (those are explicitly mentioned). Click on the app name for details if you've Javascript enabled :)